# How to display figures instead of letters in position analysis notation in ChessBase?

Tags: software, chessbase, fritz

I just installed Deep Fritz 14 with ChessBase. By default the notation in deep position analysis looks like this (only letters, no chess figures):
[image]

I would like to make it look like this:
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, figured it out.

File > options > Clocks+Notations > Figurines radio button